# Ubuntu 16.04.3 system randomly "crashes" - running, but unresponsive/inaccessible

Tags: 16.04, crash

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 and seemingly at random I cannot wake the system. When this happens:

- The tower is on, but the monitors are blank with the power led's
  flashing
- The system won't wake with any keyboard or mouse activity and I have
  to  use a hard reset to regain access.
- I am unable to switch to any tty.
- I cannot access the system with ssh from another machine.

Sometimes this will happen after being up for a week, sometimes a day or two.

I have run an extended memtest with no errors.

It happened today and below is a pastebin of the system log from the last boot until the "crash" last night at 23:16:17:

https://pastebin.com/WR0bZjnv

Can anyone see anything in there? Any suggestions for how I can trace the problem? As it stands, I can't leave anything "in progress" because the system could be inaccessible any time I leave it and return.

Comment: Can you access it remotely, as ssh? Maybe some I/O issue, since apparently, your server is running well, according to posted syslog.

Comment: No remote access, ssh fails to connect

Comment: Show me `ls -alt /var/crash` and temporarily disable ALL GNOME extensions (or top panel extesnions if Unity), esp weather.

Comment: '~$ ls -alt /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Sep 30 07:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 Jan 13  2017 ..'
How do I temporarily disable all extensions? I can uninstall my-weather-indicator, but is there another way?